# move from login screen to menu screen

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy.In the below code, Once the login successfull, I am unable to move from login screen to MenuScreen (`self.parent.current = MenuScreen()`).
How to fix this?.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.labelUsername = Label(text='User Name : ',pos = (200,300))
        self.add_widget(self.labelUsername)
        self.inputUser = TextInput(pos = (300,340), multiline=False,height=40,width = 150)
        self.add_widget(self.inputUser)
        self.labelPassword = Label(text='Password :',pos = (200,250))
        self.add_widget(self.labelPassword)
        self.inputPasswd = TextInput(pos = (300,280), height=40,width = 150,password=True, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.inputPasswd)
        self.btnLogin = Button(text = 'Login',pos = (320,230),width = 100,height = 30 )
        self.add_widget(self.btnLogin)
        self.btnLogin.bind(on_press=self.get_user_passwd)

    def get_user_passwd(self,*args):
        username, passwd = self.inputUser.text,self.inputPasswd.text
        if username == passwd:
            self.parent.current = MenuScreen()
        else:
            pop_up = Popup(title="username and password should be the same.", size_hint=(.3, .3))
            pop_up.open()

class MenuScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        l = BoxLayout(cols="2")
        btn = Button(text="ad")
        l.add_widget(btn)
        print "flag" 

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        #screen_manager.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='LoginScreen'))
        #screen_manager.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
        return LoginScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Your MenuScreen is a grid layout, this cannot work. Also, you should really use kv language to describe gui, because the code is a huge, hard to read (and maintain) mess.

Comment: Please can you fix the above code without .kv file

Comment: I advice watching a tutorial, which would explain very basics to you: http://inclem.net/pages/kivy-crash-course/